# how service workers perform background operations such as fetching data from an API endpoint and getting notified even if the browser tab is closed

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I want the service worker will be fetching data from an API endpoint and get notified even if the website tab is closed.
How can I design and implement a service worker in my web application that can fetch data from an API endpoint, store the data in the cache or without cache, and display notifications to the user even when the website tab is closed

```
     //service-worker.js
            self.addEventListener("push", (e) => {
                    const data = e.data.json();
                    console.log("Push Recieved...");
                        e.waitUntil(
                            self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
                                body: data.description,
                                icon: data.icon,
                            })
                        );
                });
        
        
        
        //index.js
        
        const publicVapidKey =
            "BJthRQ5myDgc7OSXzPCMftGw-n16F7zQBEN7EUD6XxcfTTvrLGWSIG7y_JxiWtVlCFua0S8MTB5rPziBqNx1qIo";
        
        if ("serviceWorker" in navigator ) {
          
            send(users).catch((err) => {
                if (Notification.permission === "denied") {
                    console.warn("The user has blocked notifications.");
                    return;
                }
            });
        
              
           
        }
        
        
        // Register SW, Register Push, Send Push
        async function send(user) {
            // Register Service Worker
            console.log("Registering service worker...");
            const register = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(
                "/service-worker.js.js",
                {
                    scope: "/",
                }
            );
        
            // console.log(register);
            console.log("Service Worker Registered...");
        
            // Register Push
        
            console.log("Registering Push...");
            const subscriptio = await register.pushManager.subscribe({
                userVisibleOnly: true,
                applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey),
            });
        
            console.log("Push Registered...");
        
            // Send Push Notification
            console.log("Sending Push...");
           await fetch("/user/receive-notification", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({ subscriptio, user }),
                headers: {
                    Authorization:
                        "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2M2NlMDk4YTU0YTIyMDZhMzRhYzQzMjYiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImVtYWlsQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiaWF0IjoxNjc1MDc0MDk3fQ.zkvnahJh4uUlCRRxheE_24F5m55VLQWR1L04YvDO0ww",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            });
           
        
        }
        
        function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
            const padding = "=".repeat((4 - (base64String.length % 4)) % 4);
            const base64 = (base64String + padding)
                .replace(/\-/g, "+")
                .replace(/_/g, "/");
        
            const rawData = window.atob(base64);
            const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
        
            for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
                outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return outputArray;
        }
```

Comment: So, what happens when you run your code? Output of console log?

Comment: I get notified if the site is open on the browser tab but  I want the service worker will be fetching data from an API endpoint in the background and get notified even if the website tab is closed.

did you get my point?

i would like to give you an example such as the firebase setbackgroundmessagehandler function.
after allowing the notification whenever we send a notification the site receives the notification even if the site is open or not on the browser we will be got notified.

I hope you get my point.
Thanks